# Limit involving exponential

Tags: limits

Compute

$
\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}} - it/\sqrt{\lambda} - 1}{t^2/\lambda}$

Here's what I did, using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2} e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}} &= \frac{d}{d\lambda} \frac{-it}{\lambda^{3/2}}  e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}} = \frac{-t^2 e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}}{4\lambda^3} + \frac{3it e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}}{4\lambda^{5/2}} \\[8pt]
\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2} it/\sqrt{\lambda} &= \frac{3it}{4 \lambda^{5/2}} \\[8pt]
\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2} t^2/\lambda &= \frac{2t^2}{\lambda^3}\\[16pt]
\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}} - it/\sqrt{\lambda} - 1}{t^2/\lambda} &= \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{-t^2}{4\lambda^3} e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}} + \frac{3it e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}}{4\lambda^{5/2}} - \frac{3it}{4 \lambda^{5/2}}}{\frac{2t^2}{\lambda^3}}\\[16pt]
&=\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}}{8} = -1/8
\end{align}
$$

The book's solution is $-½$. I'm not sure where my mistakes are.

Comment: I did not check your computation, but as a hint try multiplying by $\lambda$ nominator and denominator, then expand the  exponential.

Comment: @Frédéric Doing so actually results in the original form of the limit - I converted it from indeterminate form $\infty \times 0$ to form $0 / 0$ to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is a following to my comment as it would not appropriate as another comment.
One gets 
$$
\dfrac{
e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}} - it/\sqrt{\lambda} - 1}
{
\dfrac{t^2}{\lambda}
}
=
\dfrac{
-t^2/2 + \sum\limits_{k=3}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(it)^k}{k!}\lambda^{1-k/2}
}{
t^2
}
$$
leading to the result of your textbook.